# Error with tensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have some problem with tensorFlow. I'm trying to install it with GPU on my manjaro linux with GTX 1060.

When I try to import tensorFlow in python with:

`import tensorflow as tf`

I get this error:

> {...} ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory {...}

With pip, I have installed tensorFlow-gpu:`sudo pip install tensorflow-gpu`

When I try to install cuda-8.0 (with `pacaur -Syu cuda-8.0`), after a very long loading, I got an error. Now when I try to install it, it does this:

> Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded

Even if it's not on my pacaur list, and there is no reinstalling signed

---

I have install Keras with: `sudo pip install Keras`

I have install cudNN with: `pacaur -Syu cudnn`

I have installed my nvidia driver with (if I remember it right):`pacaur -Syu nvidia`

Comment: You have to find out why cuda-8.0 could not be installed, the full pacaur output contains a lot more information that what you poster. Additionally, this is not a programming problem, it belongs in the Super Users site.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with manjaro. Assume you wanna install TensorFlow 1.4, the order would be:

1. Install latest Nvidia driver (version 384.xx or higher). Check its status in a terminal with `nvidia-smi`.
2. Install CUDA 8.0 without the GPU driver (as you have done it in step 1).
3. Add `PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin` to the environment (in Ubuntu it's `/etc/environment`).
4. Added driver and CUDA paths to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. In Ubuntu, it is done by adding `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/lib/nvidia-384:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}` to `/etc/bash.bashrc`. At this point, you should be able to check CUDA version by `nvcc --version`.
5. Copy CUDNN files to somewhere and add that path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. CUDNN needs no installation.
6. Install TensorFlow 1.4.

If you wanna install other versions of TensorFlow, you need to first check the supported versions of CUDA and CUDNN.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that cuda-8.0 isn't installed. `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/` doesn't exit

Comment: Hoe about downloading the runfile of cuda and running that (`sudo sh cuda_8.0.xx_linux.run`) for installation, instead of `pacaur -Syu cuda-8.0`?